# DomDocument won't load HTML -- "Allowed memory size ... exhausted" error

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to parse an HTML page using `DomDocument`, but when I try calling the `loadHTML()` function I get the following PHP error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   32983304 bytes)

Echoing out the `strlen()` of the HTML gives `357878`.

If a UTF-8 character is 1 byte, then the size of the HTML string is 0.3MB. However, according to the PHP error, `DomDocument` attempted to allocate 31.5MB!

Here's all I'm doing:

```
$dom = new \DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
die;
```

Is this normal?

**UPDATE:**

I found adding:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Causes it to start working!

I don't know if this test is accurate or not, but I tried adding this to the constructor of my class (it's a very lightweight class that doesn't do much):

```
$this->startingMemoryUsage = memory_get_usage(true);
```

Then this right after `$dom->loadHtml()`:

```
echo (memory_get_usage(true) - memory_get_usage());
```

And the output was:

```
561360
```

Which is 0.5MB -- pretty much exactly what it should be based on my previous HTML string size calculation.

So, for some reason, it appears DomDocument tries to allocate a ton of memory when I don't have `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`, but then when I add that line it magically starts working.

Comment: Doesn't sound too crazy - you don't have much info, so it may not be that DOMDocument needs to store 32MB permanently, just that it needs to alloc 32MB while it's building the document tree. In any case, 32MB may not be small, but it's not the only thing taking up your memory. Maybe you have some arrays you can `unset()` before you call this?

Comment: No that's not normal, whys is the script already using up 90 odd mb, Your doing something wrong, please explain what your code does, that cant be all of it, so its impossible to know what's wrong...

Comment: I think utf-8 strings have 4 byte chars. Anyway, you could always cheat with `ini_set('memory_limit','128M');` or `ini_set('memory_limit,'-1');` but that is a bandaid more than anything else

Comment: @Nate do you handle your own errors? `set_error_handler` ect, you most likely filled up a variable there with the XML errors or memory leak in that area.

Comment: @LozCherone - Yes, I'm using `set_error_handler()` and `register_shutdown_function` to save errors in a database instead of displaying them on the page. I tried commenting those out and running the `DomDocument` script again and hundreds of warnings similar to `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,` displayed on the page! Could you make your comment an answer, and maybe elaborate a little more on why this happened? Thanks!!!

Comment: When you dont handle your own errors, errors are sent out as they come in, which uses minimal memory.Where you handle your own, your assigning them errors to variables which uses memory, as your loading a large file that will show lots of errors your filling something in your error handler and its not getting freed which is leaking memory. You answered your own question in your case, the best course of action is to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` and have a look at your error handler to see if can be improved. +1 Was a **nice** find though, I would of been scratching my head for hours.

Comment: @LozCherone Thanks, that helps a lot! Not sure what I could do differently, since I just directly save errors to a database in my error handler, but I guess for now I can just include `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` in the script. Want to make your comments an answer?

Comment: `unset` everything in your error handler after it has written to the db, and free all results, either `mysqli_result::free` or `mysqli_free_result`

Comment: @LozCheroneツ - Do you want to make your comments an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`, then that is the cause of the memory leak because the error list is growing.